# Comparing two values and adding subsequent columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having two sheets and need to compare two columns, A and X such that if the values match then the value in front of the cell in column A, i.e column B is returned.

```
 Column A    Column B                        Column X        Column Y
 123            50                              456          100 
 456          100                               334
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

`VLOOKUP` is what you are looking for.

In column Y2: `=VLOOKUP(X2;A1:B3;2;FALSE)`

Using `VLOOKUP` you can find values in a table or matrix. Using it is quite simple:

`=VLOOKUP(*lookupvalue*;*MATRIX*;*columnindex*;*rangelookup*)`

The columnindex is based on your matrix.

Example: If your matrix is G1:J20, G* would have the columnindex 1, H* 2, I* 3, J* 4.

Range Lookup:
TRUE assumes the first column in the table is sorted either numerically or alphabetically, and will then search for the closest value. This is the default method if you don't specify one.

FALSE is looking for the exact match.

More information can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

I've created you an example. Please note that I'm using a german excel client - therefore my formula isn't `VLOOKUP`, it is "sverweis"...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxW3WdSITmbjTEw1bm1Gb2l1eWc

Comment: Though your answer may be correct, it is often helpful to include why your answer is the solution and how it works. It would also be nice if you include a link to a resource of some kind (like MS) for additional information if the OP needs it.

Comment: This solution works for Y2, but will give error for Y3, instead of resulting in "" as shown in the question

Comment: What? For Y3 it's obviously =VLOOKUP(X3;A1:B3;2). It will result in "" because X3 can't be found on his matrix, as there is no 334...

Comment: Much better! Good job.

Comment: @Andre: "If range_lookup is FALSE, the #N/A error value indicates that the exact number isn't found." from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1. Your second version is indeed looks great, congratulation!

Comment: @MátéJuhász you are right :) I forgot about setting the range_lookup to false. It's been a while since I've used excel formulas :)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot guys. You are awesome !!! :)

Comment: Also can anyone tell me how to trim convert following    12345-6-7 to 12345,12346,12347. Thanks