# compare two sheets using vlookup

Tags: worksheet-function

I have two excel sheets, 1st sheet (very long list, e.g 15 person) named register  has 2 columns-  ID and Name.  2nd sheet (shorter list e.g 8 person turn up ) named attendance has 3 columns - ID, Name and date
I want to compare both sheets and have a 3rd column in 1st sheet with the vlookup formula. Person who appear in the 2nd sheet will be shown up in 3 rd column of 1st sheet. meaning the date will be shown.

What would be the formula (with absolute values)?

Comment: welcome at superuser. Vlookup has several tutorials on the internet please have a look on them. If you still can't solve your problem please share with us what have you tried and why that doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to my answer given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/970970/comparing-two-values-and-adding-subsequent-columns/970979?noredirect=1)

Depending on what value you are looking for (ID or name) your formula would look like the following:

Lookup by Name:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!B1:C16;2;FALSE)
```

Lookup by ID:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!A1:C16;3;FALSE)
```

Formula:

[image]

Data:

[image]

Remember: VLOOKUP always checks for the first column given in your matrix! For that reason you've got two different formulas, based on what you are looking up for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually surf the internet for answers but was not really successful. I tried what u mentioned but kept getting an error msg.

Comment: Maybe share your file then.

Comment: Oh I was playing around the formula by reading up more help and I managed to get it.